# Update one column in an uploaded document to another column value in the same list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a document library that contains client applications. It has fields for client account number, application effective date, and application end date. All files are uploaded in one format: [Account Number].[Date]. I have a workflow that parses out the account number and date, and inserts them into the Account Number and Application Effective Date, respectively.

What I would like to do is that whenever another application for the same account number is uploaded, it inserts the new Application Effective Date into the old application's Application End Date column. So basically, if Account #1234 had an application effective 12/31/2016 and sent in a new one on 4/13/2017, the first record's End Date gets updated to 4/13/2017.

Is this possible to do without code? I was thinking of creating a workflow that compares the new document's Account Number to the old one's and updates the End Date, but I can't figure out a way to do it in Sharepoint Designer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your scenario, yes you can do that without code via SharePoint Designer as the following:

- Open your SharePoint Designer > Click on workflow > from the above ribbon > click on list workflow > select your library.
- set the name of workflow > edit workflow > add a new action from the above ribbon > called `Update List Item`

> Update item in this list

Configure your action as shown below

[image]